# Remove parent category from url

Tags: magento-1

I want to make 2 url for same subcategory to point on same think example:
/cat1/cat2/cat3 - this on is made when i add category
/cat1/cat3 - i want to make this one as well. At the moment it's returing 404 page

I add cat3 in subcategory cat2. At the moment link to cat3 is cat1/cat2/cat3. I just want to remove cat2 from link or create new link cat1/cat3 who will show same think as cat1/cat2/cat3. Right now cat1/cat3 returns 404.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up parameters in URL Rewrite Management like this, on cat1/cat3 page you will see products from cat3_id without redirection you to cat1/cat2/cat3 page:

ID Path: cat1/cat2/cat3

Request Path: cat1/cat3

Target Path: catalog/category/view/id/cat3_id

Redirect: no

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **custom rewrite** to redirect CMS pages, or any other type of page.

Before you begin, **figure out the URL keys that you need for the ID Path, Request Path, and Target Path**.

> Just remember— the “Request Path” is the old URL, and the “ID Path”
>   and “Target Path” are the new URL.

On the **Admin menu**, select **Catalog > URL Rewrite Management**.

**Add URL Rewrite**

In your case

ID Path: `cat1/cat2/cat3`

Request Path: `cat1/cat3`

Target Path: `cat1/cat2/cat3`

Redirect: `Permanent (301)`

**[Source](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/search_seo/seo-url-rewrite-custom-create.html)**

Comment: Is there a way to make cat1/cat2/cat3 and cat1/cat3 like two seperate urls returning the same think. Or just to remove cat2 from url?

Comment: @miso911 means this both link will point to third link?

Comment: Have you tried my answer? @miso911 it will redirect cat1/cat3 to cat1/cat2/cat

Comment: I add cat3 in subcategory cat2. At the moment link to cat3 is cat1/cat2/cat3. I just want to remove cat2 from link or create new link cat1/cat3 who will show same think as cat1/cat2/cat3. Right now cat1/cat3 returns 404.

Comment: Yes it will work like that @miso911

Comment: I try this and it's only redirect from cat1/cat3 to cat1/cat2/cat3 what i don't want. I want to create new url like cat1/cat3 and make it show same think as cat1/cat2/cat3. So that cat1/cat3 become link of subcategory cat3.